# Xuggler retrieve audio Samples for each channel from video

Tags: java, audio, sampling, xuggler

I use Xuggler and the DecodeAndPlayVideo demo, and it works great.

Now I would like retrieve each sample from each channel audio to do another process after.

I would Like  a solution like this (or other):

```
IAudioSample channelRight 
IAudioSample channelLeft
```

I tryed with this code, but doesn't work well  :

```
//aSample is the main IAudioSamples (Stereo )

byte[] leftChanelByte = new byte[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < leftChanelByte.length ; i++) {

    leftChanelByte[i]= (byte)aSamples.getSample(i, 1, aSamples.getFormat());
}
```

Have you any idea to do this? 
Thanks